# Se listan los archivos de la ruta principal Laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

Alguien sabe porque se listan los archivos de la ruta principal ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No redirige a ningun lado :

```
Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
```

});
Route::get('/CMO/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Answer (score 0):

Porque el front de tu sitio en Laravel está en la carpeta public, entonces debes acceder a ella a través de esta url

localhost/CMO/public

cuando hagas deploy a tu server debes apuntar el dominio a la carpeta public para que no pase esto.

Tambien puedes crear un host virtual para que en tu localhost accedas a través de un dominio personalizado por ejemplo misitio.dominiocustom

ejemplo https://medium.com/@jhordydelaguila/creando-y-configurando-virtual-host-con-apache-para-xampp-windows-f90c2b0527ac

Answer (score 0):

El problema que tienes es con la configuración de tu Apache, que se encuentra en el archivo httpd.conf en la ruta /conf/httpd.conf. En dicho archivo debe existir una directiva que regula el acceso a la carpeta raíz.

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```